# nacl_io. Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: ssl, https, websocket, openssl, google-nativeclient

I wrote the chrome packaged app which works as websocket server. It works fine at 'ws://127.0.0.1:9876' connection but doesn't at 'wss://127.0.0.1:9876'. Connection with the websocket client was established but **SSL handshake hangs** at **SSL_accept()** function (several attempts) and drops connection in timeout (in my case 5 seconds).

```
[2016/04/23 05:06:37:2455] DEBUG: SSL_accept failed 2 / error:00000002:lib(0):func(0):system lib
[2016/04/23 05:06:37:2458] INFO: SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
[2016/04/23 05:06:43:0539] NOTICE: wsi 0xfe4be090: TIMEDOUT WAITING on 9 (did hdr 0, ah 0xfe1e0008, wl 0, pfd events 0)
```

In other side, websocket client tells that the webserver closed connection (chrome.exe)

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:9876/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

The same result if I launch openssl test:

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect 127.0.0.1:9876
CONNECTED(00000003)
6280256:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 318 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

To build I had ported to naclports/webports libwebsockets (ver.2.0 https://libwebsockets.org/) and openssl (1.0.2e). Also, I had generated my self-signed certificate and private key and hardcoded into the my code. It seems the issue is not related to certificate due to my built libwebsockets-test-server on ubuntu works fine with the same clients.

1. Does anyone have an idea how to **create secure Websocket or HTTPS SSL connection in nacl code** ?
2. How to change 'canonical_hostname = naclhost' to my domain name like 'abcd.com' ?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your server is not sending its certificate.

Comment: @jww, thank you for suggestion, the same certificates work fine in Ubuntu server assembled with the same source code, moreover, if I set the socket into bocked state, SSL_acept hangs infinite. It seems there is undocumented nacl behaviour. Also, I've got the same result with signed on COMODO trusted certificate. It seems the certificate does not matter,

Comment: Use `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:9876 -tls1 -servername 127.0.0.1`. That utilizes TLS 1.0 and SNI. If that does not work, then provide the certificate from 127.0.0.1.